# SEM with zero-inflated outcome

Tags: regression, latent-variable, zero-inflation, structural-equation-modeling

I'm working on a project and my advisor wants me to do SEM in MPLUS because we can do latent modeling, but I have no clue where to start. I've only ever done regressions but I said I'd be up for learning SEM. The project is a bit complicated for me, but I will try to break it down. Any direction or suggestions would be helpful.

1) The raw data will create combined variables.
2) These combined variables will load onto factors.
3) These factors will relate to the outcome. 
3) There will be a mediator between the factors and the outcome.
4) The outcome is zero-inflated.

How should I tackle this?
In completing preliminary analyses, I have created the combined variables. These are all positively skewed. I then created the factor structures (z transformed the combined variables and added them together) that I expected to come out. One of the factors was normally distributed. The outcome is zero-inflated.

Comment: Does MPLUS have a SEM manual?  If not, Stata's SEM manual has information on the basics of SEM (if you have not used SEM before). Link: http://www.stata.com/manuals13/sem.pdf

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking... I have Principles and Practice of Structural Equation Modeling by Kline and I also have another book specific to SEM with MPLUS. Someone offered to provide the code for the path analysis... but right now, I need to understand enough to write up an analysis plan before I dive into analyses.